# accessing app from public ip

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have one linux server which has one public ip. I have deployed one webapp which I can access using internal ip address like - `http://[internal_IP]:8080/blackbox/Index.jsp` which works. but when I try to access the same from public ip `http://[public_IP]:8080/blackbox/Index.jsp`, it does not work. Can you please suggest how can I make it work?

Comment: What does "does not work"? State the exact error you get. Also, make sure the port is open to the outside world.

Comment: if port 8080 is not open to world, what are the options.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Tomcat is listening on your public interface by:

```
netstat -an
```

Listening on `*:8080` is ok, but `127.0.0.1:8080` means it is only listening on the local loopback interface.

Also check your topology. There can be a local firewall software stopping incoming traffic. Also if you are behind a NAT, the port has to be forwarded to your macine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a consumer grade router, it might be the problem. I've come across way too many cheap routers that got confused when you tried to connect from your LAN to your external IP... But it all works fine if you connect from outside your LAN.

So check that other networking services or such work if you connect using your external IP.

Answer (score 0):

It can be your [linux firewall](http://www.physics.umd.edu/pnce/user-docs/Linux/firewall.html#allowed_chain), or your router is not [portforwarded](http://screenshots.portforward.com/) for this service.